# Let $\phi: R^2\to R^2$ by $\phi(x_1,x_2)=(y_1,y_2)=(x_1x_2,1)$ Compute the following...

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $\phi: R^2\to R^2$ by $\phi(x_1,x_2)=(y_1,y_2)=(x_1x_2,1)$

Compute the following:

(a) $\phi^*(dy_1)$

(b) $\phi^*(dy_2)$

(c) $\phi^*(y_2dy_1)$

I don’t even know where to start. I’m not sure what the star notation signifies. I found a solution online but I cant make any sense of it. Could someone please explain the method here?

Comment: This is the [pullback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_%28differential_geometry%29#Pullback_of_differential_forms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical notation makes this confusing for several reasons, so I will say $\phi(x_1, x_2) = (f_1(x_1, x_2), f_2(x_1, x_2))$ is the mapping in question in hopes of clearing some of this up. In this notation, $f_1(x_1, x_2) = x_1x_2$, and $f_2(x_1, x_2) = 1$. The meaning of $\phi^*(dy_1)$ is $df_1$, expressed in terms of $dx_1$ and $dx_2$, since $y_1 = f_1(x_1, x_2)$ describes the $y_1$-coordinate of $\phi$. Now, one uses the Leibniz/product rule:
$$
\phi^*(dy_1) = d(x_1 \cdot x_2) = x_2 dx_1 + x_1dx_2.
$$
Similarly, $\phi^*(dy_2) = 0$; this is not unexpected, since $\phi$ is constant in the $y_2$-direction.

Does this check out with your understanding of the cotangent vectors $dx_i, dy_j$? Does this help to understand the other solution you found?

Comment: Ok, are parts a and c the same then, since $y_2$=1?

Comment: Yes, exactly. (c) reduces to $f_2 df_1 = df_1$.

Comment: Ok, for b i have then that, $d(f_2)=d(x_1x_2*1)=d(1)=0$?

Comment: Well, $f_2(x_1, x_2) = 1$, so (b) should be $\phi^*(dy_2) = d1 = 0$ since the differential of a constant is zero. Alternatively, just using Leibniz, $d1 = d(1 \cdot 1) = d1 + d1 = 2d1$, so $d1 = 0$.

Comment: Yeah I just realized and edited it

Comment: Ok for (a) then is there another step past $x_1dx_2+x_2dx_1$? I don’t see it if there is...

Comment: I don't think so? I would certainly consider that a final answer.

Comment: Cool, thx. Just making sure

Comment: My bad, I thought accepting the answer awarded the bounty. Thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

$\phi^*dy_1$ by its very definition is a 1-form on domain (the left-hand side $\mathbb{R}^2$) that acts as the following: For every vector $v$ based at $(x,y)$,
$$ \phi^*dy_1 (v) = dy_1(D\phi(x,y) v) = first \ component \ of \ the \ vector \ D\phi(x,y) v \ . $$
To know any form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ it suffices to know its action on $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. So, let's compute:
$$ D\phi(x,y) (1,0) = (\partial/\partial_x (x_1 x_2), \partial/\partial_x (1))=(x_2,0) ,$$
Hence
$$ \phi^*dy_1 (1,0) = dy_1(D\phi(x,y) (1,0)) = x_2 \ .$$
Similarly,
$$ \phi^*dy_1 (0,1) = dy_1(D\phi(x,y) (1,1)) = x_1 \ .$$
Together, they give, by linearity,
$$ \phi^*dy_1 = x_2 dx_1 + x_1 dx_2 \ . $$
Apply the same reasoning to other cases.